# FreePBX AND Wireless Bridge on same RasPi?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

I have a RasPi 3 and I want to install FreePBX onto it AND I want to use it as a wireless bridge.

Meaning, when it's setup I want to use the RasPi 3's wifi to connect to my home wifi and then use the RasPi 3's ethernet port to connect to my VOIP phone.

So, can one RasPi do both, run as a PBX AND also be a wireless bridge?

If it comes down to processing power, I also have a RasPi 4 I could use.

Comment: What is FreePBX?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified concurrent calls and if you are doing transcoding in Asterisk, but the short answer is YES a raspberry Pi 3 can do both if you don't have a lot of transcoding and playing a lot of voice prompts.